# undefined variable though it has exist as class filed list in php

Tags: php

I am a beginner in php and I use java at before. 
this is my php class code:

```
class Set
{
    private $_set;

    public function __construct(){
        $_set = array();
    }

    public function add($val){
        print($_set);
    }
}
```

it tell me **undefined variable $_set** in add function. But the variable **$_set** has already exist as field variable. So, I dont know why I cant access field variable in add function.

Comment: HINT `$this->` when using class properties from within the class

Comment: print($this->_set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Set
{
    private $_set;

    public function __construct(){
        this->_set = array();
    }

    public function add($val){
        print($this->_set);
    }
}
```

> you have to use `$this->` to address the classes properties.

For more ref http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php